# Azure Managed Application: encrypting disk by custom key

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-marketplace

I need to store sensitive data in VM in Managed App published on Azure Marketplace.

Each customer can make snapshot of the VM's disk and restore data.

I need ability to encrypt disk by key stored in my own KeyVault. Is it possible? Or maybe someone knows another way to protect data on the disk of Managed Application?

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to make copies of the disk (snapshot/backup)?  By default in an AMA they would not be able to...  Also, not sure how restore would work since the users would not have access to the vault.

Comment: @bmoore-msft Thank you. You are right. User can't make snapshot of the disk. But he can create VM from image on marketplace. Can I encrypt this image on Azure Marketplace? I use the image only from my own Managed Application.

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? or what exactly you expect?

Comment: ah... so you want to protect the vm image "at rest" in the marketplace?  Once it's published and running in the managed app you can control whether or not any customer can get to it...  you want to secure it while sitting in the image repo?

Answer (score 0):

> I need ability to encrypt disk by key stored in my own KeyVault. Is it
>   possible?

Of course, it's possible. You can create your own Keyvault and store the key in it, then encrypt the VM disk with the key. Follow the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/disk-encryption-key-vault).

It's free if you have more questions, just let me know :-)